# MYSQL query that finds an ID that was only added after a specific date

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble trying to come up with a specific mysql query. I haven't even found any reference close to what I am looking for. I am not sure if I am searching the right questions...

I have a database that stores a list of unique ids. The ids then get unique entries in the database whenever they do something. So it isn't unusual for one id to appear hundreds of times each month in my database. I have about 5 years worth of ids currently in the database. The query I am looking to build is to identify the IDs that are new since the beginning of June.

So far the only queries that I have been able to come up with all specify specific ids in June, where I want the ids that first appeared in June and never before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: 
I have a timestamp of when every entry was added to the table

Comment: Do you have a date field in your table?

Comment: I do! Sorry, I should have specified that in my post.

Comment: And you want to use the action table, instead of say an account creation date?

Comment: I currently only have one table. The accounts that are being stored are created long before they get to the database, I am just storing their transactions with a timestamp of when it was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(ID) as ID 
    FROM YOUR_TABLE 
    WHERE DATE >= "2018/06/01") b 
WHERE b.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(ID) as ID 
    FROM YOUR_TABLE 
    WHERE DATE < "2018/06/01")
```

It creates a selection of id's before and after june, then compares them for new ones after june.  An easier way to do it is just set a first action column on the user to denote when they became "active" though.

Comment: Awesome, I am going to give this a shot right now and I'll let you know how it goes. I completely agree with the first action column. I am actually going to take note of that and look at implementing it. It would have been way easier.

Comment: Hey this worked well for what I was looking for, I only had to change it to 
     SELECT * (....
My numbers were a little off with this, but this gives me a strong starting point. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem glad to help!

Comment: One of the `>` or `<` should be `>=` or `<=`. Otherwise you're excluding items where `date = '2018/06/01'`

Comment: Updated with >=